# Code comments now generating compiler errors

Tags: c

I am trying to recompile an older project where a colleague has added few more adventurous comments (ok, these are Doxygen comments, I forgot)

For instance the triple `///`

```
uint32_t nx; ///< number of columns
```

It was developed with 4.2 and now with 4.8 the compiler generates the following error:

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘/’ token

Should I get rid of all `///` expressions and replace with `//`? It's a large project

Comment: Change compiler options. `-std=c99` should be better for instance.

Comment: `///` and `///<` are used for document tools as doxygen, but you should be in a mode where `//` is a regular comment.

Comment: You should follow his guidance. These are [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/index.html) comments for automatic documentation generation. But you should use a standard-compliant compiler or at least a C99 compatible. The version number alone is useless. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Oh, and don't add irrelevant tags! This problem obviously is about C, not C++.

Comment: If `//` is well recognized as a comment, there is no reason `///` is not. So replacing `///` with `//` won't help.

Comment: I know that '//' should be the default and everything behind should be ignored.gcc 4.8.5 &  '--std=c++98' When I just delete them it's good to go

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`//` comments do not work with `-std=c89` or `-ansi` options. Use `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` instead.

Comment: @ElDude g++ refuses `-std=c99` and gcc rejects `-std=c++98`. What compiler you use that accepts both of them?

Comment: It's a C++ project with a C core, so obviously C99 is wrong for all and C++99 as well.

Comment: @ElDude You just told me your compiler accepts `-std=c99`, so gcc should be executed, not g++, right?

Comment: It's complicated... :) I figured it out now. 1) I deleted all ///> and // entries . 2) I use c99 for the C files and c++98 for the C++ files. It just compiled...